# Tool for ActiveX Control Capabilities

Tags: com, activex, uuid

Is there a tool out there that allows me to browse all the ActiveX controls I have installed on my system and the methods and properties that I can access? And of course their UUIDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oleview](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6&displaylang=en) which comes with every Windows SDK, look under the controls section.
You can see the methods if you right click on the object and select "*View type Information...*".

[http://twitpic.com/7g2je http://twitpic.com/show/large/7g2je](http://twitpic.com/show/large/7g2je)